# What are network domains?

Tags: networking, mount, domain

When I log in at work, I am on NT.xyz.com domain.

But work on my project, via Linux, has to be through project.xyz.com.

I can navigate to project.xyz.com via Windows Explorer, after authenticating, and see various shared folders there.

But I'm having troubles connecting my Linux VM to the network and mounting everything as it needs to be, so I hope you guys can give me some more information about this.

Particularly, is there any way to discover how a Network looks, all the possible hostnames and shares I could connect to, etc?

One problem is that I originally tried connecting my VM to the shares in the same way I did over Windows.

```
mount -t smbfs -o username=,password= //xyz.com/project /project
```

I later discovered a different VM had mounted this instead:

```
mount xyz.com:/some/weird/path/i/cant/remember /project
```

I tried copying all the mounts I could find to my own VM, but it didn't work. One of the mounts was to /project/tools, which can an error about subdirectory dept, and the other was to /home/myuser, which gave an error about authentication!

Answer (score 0):

Does your workplace have IT support? If so, they're the best ones to start with.

There are commands in linux to list shares available on a host, and there's ways to find out what hosts are available on the local network, but really, unless you want to play and learn (in which case there's plenty of guides online on how to get started with linux) you're better off just connecting to just what you need and moving on :)